# Parsing JSON with Increment Object Name using Moshi and Retrofit in Kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, retrofit, moshi

I am getting a JSON via an API that looks like that.

[image: JSON File]

As you can see the first object name is an **increment value**. How do I have to handle that variable object name in the data class or the interface using moshi?
For 'normal' JSON files this code is working. Is there a way to make the data class object name variable or how to change the interface to create a constant name?

Data Class:

```
data class PhilipsHueLightsApi(
    val lightId: List<HueLight>
)

data class HueLight(
    val state: HueLightState,
    val swupdate: HueLightSwupdate,
    val type: String,
    val name: String,
    val modelid: String,
    val manufacturername: String,
    val productname: String,
    val capabilities: HueLightCapabilities,
    val config: HueLightConfig,
    val uniqueid: String,
    val swversion: String
)

data class HueLightState (
    val on: Boolean,
    val bri: Int,
    val hue: Int,
    val sat: Int,
    val effect: String,
    val xy: HueLightColorCode,
    val ct: Int,
    val alert: String,
    val colormode: String,
    val mode: String,
    val reachable: Boolean
)...
```

API Service:

```
interface OpenPhilipsHueConnection {

    /**
     * A public interface that exposes the [getPhilipsHueLightsApi] method
     */
    interface OneCallApiConnection {
        /**
         * The @GET annotation indicates that endpoint will be requested with the GET HTTP method
         */
        @GET("/$API_GET/$USER_ID/$API_SELECTION")
        suspend fun getPhilipsHueLightsApi(): Response<PhilipsHueLightsApi>
    }

    // Singleton
    object OpenPhilipsHueLightsApi {
        /**
         * Build the Moshi object with Kotlin adapter factory that Retrofit will be using.
         */
        private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()

        /**
         * The Retrofit object with the Moshi converter.
         */
        private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .build()

        val oneCallApi: OneCallApiConnection by lazy { retrofit.create(OneCallApiConnection::class.java) }
    }

}
```

Error Message:

```
I/LightRepository: Failure: Required value 'lightId' missing at $
```

Comment: Do not use screenshots of code in your question, copy paste the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your definition of `PhilipsHueLightsApi` is that of an object with one property `lightId` of type `List<HueLight>`, and that doesn't match the JSON.
The JSON you get is also an object, but it has multiple properties with names that just happen to be numbers, and there are no lists (or JSON arrays) involved here.

This format would be represented better using a `Map<String, HueLight>` instead of the `PhilipsHueLightsApi` class.
You should probably try to define your API like this:

```kotlin
suspend fun getPhilipsHueLightsApi(): Response<Map<String, HueLight>>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. Sadly it doen't work: `I/LightRepository: Failure: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at path $.1.state.xy`

Comment: @Ohlsen the problem is deeper in your model then. You should try to understand the error message, it really contains all the info you need. See the path in the error, you have defined the property `xy` as an object in Kotlin, but it's a list in the JSON. You should fix that as well in your Kotlin declaration. You have hidden the content of the JSON array there, so I can't help with the details, but it should be pretty straightforward

Comment: you were right. It is working now. Thank you so much for your support!! This helped me a lot.